# D3 => NVD3.js Updating other graphs on the same page

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I want to accomplish the same thing that's going on on the [NVD3 site](http://NVD3.org)

When you click on one graph the other graphs updates.

Looking at the js for the site, this is what does the magic

```
chart.stacked.dispatch.on('areaClick.updateExamples', function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      mainExample.update();
      exampleOne.update();
      //exampleTwo.update();
      exampleThree.update();
    }, 100);
  })
```

I don't understand what the 'updatesExamples' in the first line is. Is it a function, a variable. I can't find it anywhere else in the code. I have duplicated the code into my app, but I believe that this word is the key to get it to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`updatesExamples` is an event namespace. You could add whatever string you want. This is a feature of **d3.js** Check the docs [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Internals#wiki-d3_dispatch).

Multiple things can trigger events and for code organization you might want to namespace events. For example, in *NVD3* if you want something to happen when a **legend** is clicked you can add an event handler like this

```
chart.legend.dispatch.on('legendClick.hi', function(e){
  console.log('legend was clicked', 'namespace:', 'hi');
});
```

Here, the event being listened to, is `legendClick` and the namespace is `hi`. You can add another handler with a different namespace that will also be triggered when the legend is clicked.

```
chart.legend.dispatch.on('legendClick.there', function(e){
  console.log('legend was clicked', 'namespace:', 'there');
});
```

Namespaces are **optional** you might just pass the name of the event to the `on` method.

```
chart.legend.dispatch.on('legendClick', function(e){
  console.log('legend was clicked', 'no namespace.');
});
```

You can play with this in the live code example here: http://nvd3.org/livecode/#codemirrorNav

Comment: Please also note, that if you use no namespace, or you use the same namespace as someone before, then you will replace the existing listeners. So if you for example if you say piechart.pie.dispatch.on('elementover',function(e){return null;}) this will result in loosing the tooltip functionality of piechart, which is based on the elementover event of the pie objects. So use a namespace to avoid overwriting existing event handlers as well.